# Floating content of UIScrollView when smaller

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I'm trying to make kind of collage, so I want to resize image and drag it to any position of scroll view. Currently I can drag image only when it is bigger than scroll view. But when it is smaller than it sticks to top left corner. Yes, I can use scrollViewDidZoom to move image to center for example, but it is not what I'm looking for. For example I want to allow users to drag an image to any position of the scroll view, like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do that I just merge big empty image with my image I want to move. Looks like a bad solution, but it working as I wanted